# Visual Code lacking functionality for viewing Oracle packages?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Code to view all of the database objects in our Oracle database that I scripted to files. I installed the extension "Language PL/SQL" found here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.plsql-language

On the extension download website page mentioned above, if you look at the animate GIF, it gives the impression that if you type "@" in the command palette that the extension should list all of the procedures in an Oracle package that I have open, but instead it gives me a message under the popup: "No Editor symbols."

Is it someone possible to either jump to a procedure within a package or better yet, see an outline of the package so, as I scroll through it, I can tell which procedure I am currently in?

Comment: This is probably better posed to the git issues page https://github.com/zabel-xyz/plsql-language/issues

Comment: @Nik Thanks, I submitted my question there. https://github.com/zabel-xyz/plsql-language/issues/90

Comment: You may also want to check out Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Oracle function DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to get the DDL for a package. If you don't pass a version number into the function, the PACKAGES contain the word "CREATE OR REPLACE ** EDITIONABLE *** PACKAGE . The extension as choking on the word EDITIONABLE. So, I told the GET_DDL function to give me version 11.2 compatible DDL  and the extension was worked